# Can I set position of an element in css with respect to another element?

Tags: html, css

I want to set the bottom of the following div according to 100px less than the 100% of the page. Can I do this. (The following code doesn't work)

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#000000;
  left:40px;
  BOTTOM:100% - 100PX;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Try `bottom: 100px`

Comment: nope, I want it 100px less than 100px.

Comment: 100px less than 100px would be 0.

Comment: Sorry 100% - 100px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for:

```
bottom: calc(100vh - 100px);
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could just do this:

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#000000;
  left:40px;
  bottom: 100px;

  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I want to take 100% of the height of the page and then set the bottom to its value which would be 100px less than it. This is because using bottom is a bit challenging, I will need to change its value if the height thw webpage increases.

Comment: I want it to be 100% - 100px. This is because if the height of the website increases, I would also need to change the bottom of the webpage.